# PHP Array merge with same value

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I'm trying to merge data with same **item** but different **serial**. Result should combine the **serial** with the same **item**. I've tried **array_merge_recursive** but does not work.

Item 84UZ9200143 array should be

```
array(
'item' => '84UZ9200143',
'qty' => 4,
'serial' => '1001,1002,1003,1004'
)
or
array(
'item' => '84UZ9200143',
'qty' => 4,
'serial' => array('1001',1002,1003,1004)
)
```

This is my current array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item] => LB5532024
            [qty] => 1
            [serial] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [item] => 84UZ9200143
            [qty] => 1
            [serial] => 1001
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [item] => 84UZ9200143
            [qty] => 1
            [serial] => 1002
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [item] => 84UZ9200143
            [qty] => 1
            [serial] => 1003
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [item] => 84UZ9200143
            [qty] => 1
            [serial] => 1004
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [item] => MFC-540
            [qty] => 100
            [serial] => asda
        )

)
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: This can be achieved using iteration of array, there is no direction function which will give you the result you expect.

1. item serial would be unique, 2. You want to add up quantity, 3. You wan to concat serials.

Comment: @AmitShah yup you're right. Anyway I already solve the problem by iteration and with if else condition. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using iteration of array, There is no direction function which will give you the result you expect.

1. item serial would be unique,
2. You want to add up quantity,
3. You wan to concat serials.

Thanks
Amit